# Clarification on Caching in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

We were working on data caching in ASP.Net where we have aspx page which has a Label and a Button.
 Label will show Cached data if Cache is not null else it will load the data into cache and display "DataReloading" in the Label and a Click of a Button should clear the data from the cache and Label should show "DataReloading" and when we refresh the page again, label should show Cache Data

## Expectation:

1) when First time page loads, Label should show "DataReloading" as Cache was empty and we are loading the data

2) when we Refresh , Label should show "Cache Data" as Cache was having "Cache Data" string in it

3) When we click button to Clear cache, Label should show "DataReloading" and when we refresh the page label should show Cache Data

The Problem that we are facing is on post button click we always get "DataReloading" in the Label.

Can anyone let us know where logic is wrong.

## Here is a code from the aspx page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FormAuthenticationPractice
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                LoadCache();
        }

        private string GetData()
        {
            return "Cache Data";
        }

        protected void btnClearCache_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Cache.Remove("Data");
                lblData.Text = "DataReloading";

        }

        private void LoadCache()
        {
            if (Cache["Data"] != null)
            {
                lblData.Text = Convert.ToString(Cache["Data"]);

            }
            else
            {

                Cache["Data"] = GetData() as string;
                lblData.Text = "DataReloading";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, still did not get the resolution.